# Фреймворк Laravel

Tags: framework, php

Сабж. Юзал ли кто этот фреймворк и какие остались впечатления?

От себя скажу что за первые 10 минут знакомства с ним, у меня встал :)

*via:* http://laravel.com, http://laravel.ru, http://codehappy.daylerees.com/

Comment: @Palmervan А как же гугл?

Comment: Вот вам [статья на хабре][1]. Как всегда читать надо комменты


  [1]: http://habrahabr.ru/post/145212/

Comment: @zenith Причем тут гугл? Меня интересуют мнения людей в рамках ХэшКода! Увы блеснуть умом в данном случае у Вас не получилось.

Comment: @Palmervan у вас антропологическое исследование ? минус за неформат QA

Comment: Все такие серьезные, аж вены на висках лопаются)

Comment: @Palmervan как бэ, вы свою реакцию довольно понятно описали. Если своего субъективного мнения вам мало, тогда ищите статьи о багах. Это куда больше вам даст.  
p.s. может добавить тег sexcoding или codefelia ?

Comment: мне вот тоже например интересно. плю автору за вопрос

Comment: @Heleg интересно, это не вопрос/ответ, тема дискуссионная.

Comment: @zenith ,всё верно, давай устроим тоталитаризм на хэшкоде

Comment: Кстати, шанс получить минус за плохой вопрос/ответ обратно пропорционален карме автора вопроса/ответа.  
Сий топик тому подтверждение.